# the update query is not working in oracle sql developer , what is the error?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```sql
DECLARE
   @A varchar2(20);
BEGIN
     @A := 'abc555';

UPDATE TEST Set LINK = Replace(LINK,Substring(LINK,1,CHARINDEX('\ESSAIS-CGMP',LINK)-1),@A);

END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using Oracle not SQL server.

`SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` are not valid Oracle functions; you want `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` instead.

And, `@` is not a valid first character for a non-quoted identifier, just use `A` rather than `@A`.

```sql
DECLARE
  A varchar2(20);
BEGIN
  A := 'abc555';

  UPDATE TEST
  Set LINK = Replace(LINK,Substr(LINK,1,INSTR(link,'\ESSAIS-CGMP')-1),A);
END;
/
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test ( link VARCHAR2(50) );

INSERT INTO test ( link ) VALUES ( 'here\ESSAIS-CGMP' );
```

The result is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test;
```

> ```
> | LINK               |
> | :----------------- |
> | abc555\ESSAIS-CGMP |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c14341fa2458dff0e8870fe85777f98e)*

Comment: Hello i use this now by referring your suggestion                                                  
DECLARE
A nclob
BEGIN
A := 'abc555';
UPDATE TEST1 Set LINK1 = Replace(LINK1,SUBSTR(LINK1,1,INSTR('\ESSAIS-CGMP',LINK1)-1),A);
END;
Error Left- ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ; not null range default character
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: @RituJha you are missing a semicolon after `a nclob`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thankyou. Its working now.